# Separate environments for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What's the best way to create separate environments for BigQuery?  This will eventually be a multi-tenant system with multiple datasets for each tenant.

Comment: Can you provide more info/detail? What's the problem you're trying solve...

Comment: I'm trying to keep my data separate per environment. Normally I would just create a separate Postgres DB instance per environment. Can I do something similar with BigQuery? I want to be able to use multiple datasets per environment.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse#datasets

Comment: @Graham Polley, I was hoping to be able to use multiple datasets per environment.

Comment: I'm not following you. The diagram in that link explains how BQ is structured. That's how it works.

Comment: @Graham Polley, if you were to have a dev, stage, and production environment, how would you implement it with BigQuery?  Have a different project per environment?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.